# C++ if i have a user records within a line how can find the data to login

Tags: c++

The following code does not take the data from file.
It always displays `You have entered wrong data!!!`, and I need the code to select username and password from one line.

My record look like this: `username  password  name  id  Contactnumber`

```
if(choose ==2)//teacher
    {   
        string line=" ";
        ifstream read("teacher.txt");

        cout <<" Enter Username: "; cin >> username;
        cout <<" Enter Password: "; cin >> password;

        bool found = false;

        while (getline(read,line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            ss>>un>>pw;

            if (un == username && pw == password)
            {
                cout<<"You have logged in as Teacher!"<<endl;
                found = true;
                break;
                //system("pause");
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            cout<<"\nYou have entered wrong data!!!"<<endl;
        }
        read.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin >> username;
cin >> password;
```

Object `cin` represents standard input (keyboard by default). The file "teacher.txt" is represented by object `read` in your code. To read from this file you should write:

```
read >> username;
read >> password;
```

---

By the way, `read` is good name for function but not for object.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, it works :D